# Сelery starting task every milisecond

Tags: django, redis, celery

Celery task schedule worked fine considerate amount of time.
Now one of tasks launches and finishes successfully every couple of milliseconds.

Did some search at git/stack and found that some older celery versions suffered from this, but now its fixed. Some users experienced this problem due to celery and django TZ difference, but this is not the case.

celery version - 5.2.7
broker - redis

[flower screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NedwB.png)